# Is there a difference between set -e and set -o errexit?

Tags: linux, bash

Is there any difference between using:

```
set -e
set -o errexit
```

From the bash man page it states they are the same and the only difference I can see is that from the user perspective the second format is more explicit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're correct. `set -o <option>` is the generic way to set various options, and `set -e` is the shortcut for the `errexit` option. They have the same effect.

There are a number of shortcuts like this, as the man page indicates. `set -u` for `set -o nounset` is another commonly used option.